# How do I change my for loop to give me the right solution?

Tags: objective-c, math, for-loop

I am trying to create a loop for a mortgage amortization schedule but I am having some trouble with the logic - When adding the values to the array for principal amount it is giving me the same value each time. Is there someway to make the value of my balance change each time the loop runs?

```
double balanceAmount = loanAmountValue;
    double rtemp = r / (n * 12);
    double intA = balanceAmount * rtemp;
    double principalA = payfinal - intA;
    double principal = balanceAmount - principalA;

    for (n = n * 12; n != 0; --n) {


        double realBalance = balanceAmount - principalA;
        double interest = balanceAmount * rtemp;
        NSLog(@"%f", interest);
        double principalAmount = payfinal - interest;
        NSLog(@"%f", principalAmount);

        NSLog(@"%f", realBalance);

        NSString *tempInterest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", interest];
        [interestLabels addObject:tempInterest];
        NSString *tempPrincipal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", principalAmount];
        [pricipalLabels addObject:tempPrincipal];
        NSString *tempBalance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", realBalance];
        [balanceLabels addObject:tempBalance];

        NSLog(@"%@",pricipalLabels);
    }
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using the same variable (n) for some class variable *and* your loop variable?

Comment: n would be the number of pay periods

Comment: i need the balance to change each time the loop runs by subtracting the principal amount

Comment: I doubt you are meaning to change the number of pay periods there? It just seems weird to change the value of what seems like a class variable during a loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the balance at the end of the loop.  Try adding this: `balanceAmount -= principalA`

```
for (n = n * 12; n != 0; --n) {
    // Your other code

    balanceAmount -= principalA
}
```

Comment: Thanks! so simple yet couldn't figure it out